# php file upload and virus scan and save to ftp

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file via HTTP and run it through a virus scan and immediately move to a ftp location. Here are the basic steps,

1. Upload via HTTP
2. Do the virus scan on the php tmp directory (upload_tmp_dir) using php command line functions.
3. Move the file directly to ftp from the tmp directory after the virus check.

You might notice I am not doing a move_upload_file(), is this the best way to do it ? Or should I do steps 2 & 3 after I do a move_upload_file().

If I should not do it before move_upload_file() then what would be the reason ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the reason for the FTP moving?

Comment: The OP is not FTPing it, just putting it somewhere else that it can be accessed by FTP.

Comment: what code do you have? what does not work in it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that doing it before `move_upload_file` is appropriate.  If you move it first, then you've put a file into your FTP directory which may have a virus; for the length of time that you scan, an unsafe file is available.

Also, if you do it before `move_upload_file` and find a virus, you can just leave it there and PHP will tidy up for you; no need to call `unlink` yourself :)

Comment: Not quite. You could move it into the temp directory  with `move_upload_file`, finish the virus scan, and move it into the ftp directory.

Comment: Yes you *could* do that, but there would be no benefit to doing so.  You need to get it to the FTP source directory and there's no point in moving it somewhere else as an intermediate step.

Comment: Erm, yes there is. If you'll look at the question, you'll see that the virus scanner is a separate program. Unless you suggest passing the file via pipes, putting it into a tmp directory is needed.

Comment: PHP has already put it into a tmp directory for you; what would be the point of moving it to another one?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I didn't realize it automatically wrote uploaded files to disk.

Comment: No probs; I guess they don't want the files to hang around in memory any longer than they have to, it would potentially be murder on your server...

Comment: Thanks El, one thing forgot to ask is can we be certain the file is 100% uploaded and valid  before we call move_upload_file. The documentation says this function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism).

Comment: The check it refers to is just to ensure you're not accessing other files (e.g. `/etc/shadow` or something like that), but doesn't ensure anything about the file being uploaded.  You should check the 'error' attribute (e.g. `$_FILES['myuploadedfile']['error']`) to ensure that the file was uploaded successfully and display appropriate error messages to the user.  You will probably want to adjust the PHP settings `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` as well, to restrict uploads to an appropriate size.